# How to disable direct PHP file execution in subdirectories

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, security, server

I have noticed one issue.

I have a server running a web application. Now I can access PHP files directly from url, like that

```
http://superapp.com/libs/mongo.php
```

How can I restrict of direct execution of all PHP files except of `index.php` in the app root directory.

I would be grateful for any help

Comment: Simple: If you don't want something to be accessible via the web, don't put it in a web-accessible location. Pit it outside of the document root. You can, of course, spend a bunch of time trying to configure your server not to serve certain pages and hope that you've covered them all and managed to *not* break your application, but why not just move them outside of the document root entirely?

Comment: Or inside a password protected subdirectory...

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, people usually put the application code above (../) the public webroot to accomplish this.  Basically your wwwroot folder has index.php which includes something from ../MyApp/Bootstrap.php and maybe calls a function to kick things off.

You can disable php execution on a per folder basis, however, that is probably not what you want as it will deliver the SRC code to the requesting user.  You could use htaccess or similar to restrict requests that are not to index.php.